# Flutter app keeps crashing when opened after upgrade to null-safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

My flutter project has a multimodule and I am currently gradually updating each of them to be null-safety but unfortunately, the app kept crashing as soon as I launch the app. From the log, I don't see any specific log that is related to my app code.

LOG:

```
libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x7f9d9fe1efd8 in tid 9789 (1.ui)
03-21 00:49:51.083  6455  6455 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-21 00:49:51.083  6455  6455 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:6.0/MASTER/6695544:userdebug/test-keys'
03-21 00:49:51.083  6455  6455 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
03-21 00:49:51.083  6455  6455 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'x86_64'
03-21 00:49:51.083  6455  6455 F DEBUG   : pid: 9750, tid: 9789, name: 1.ui  >>> com.my.app <<<
03-21 00:49:51.079  6455  6455 W debuggerd64: type=1400 audit(0.0:62): avc: denied { search } for name="com.google.android.gms" dev="dm-0" ino=14680 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
03-21 00:49:51.083  6455  6455 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7f9d9fe1efd8
03-21 00:49:51.087  6455  6455 F DEBUG   :     rax 00000000000002a0  rbx 0000000000001500  rcx 0000000000000000  rdx 0000000000000015
03-21 00:49:51.087  6455  6455 F DEBUG   :     rsi 00007f9db0f422c0  rdi 00007f9db69800c0
03-21 00:49:51.087  6455  6455 F DEBUG   :     r8  0000000000000015  r9  0000000000000500  r10 000000000000000d  r11 0000000000000046
03-21 00:49:51.087  6455  6455 F DEBUG   :     r12 00007f9db0f42000  r13 00007f9db0f422c0  r14 0000000000000500  r15 0000000000000015
03-21 00:49:51.087  6455  6455 F DEBUG   :     cs  0000000000000033  ss  000000000000002b
03-21 00:49:51.087  6455  6455 F DEBUG   :     rip 00007f9db9f90f68  rbp 0000000000000000  rsp 00007f9d9fe1efd0  eflags 0000000000010206
03-21 00:49:51.087  6455  6455 F DEBUG   :
03-21 00:49:51.087  6455  6455 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
03-21 00:49:51.087  6455  6455 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00000000000a0f68  /system/lib64/libc.so (je_arena_tcache_fill_small+40)
03-21 00:49:51.087  6455  6455 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 00000000000cb1d3  /system/lib64/libc.so (je_tcache_alloc_small_hard+19)
03-21 00:49:51.087  6455  6455 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00000000000bff1d  /system/lib64/libc.so (je_malloc+1549)
03-21 00:49:51.087  6455  6455 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00000000004a80a6  /data/app/com.my.app-1/lib/x86_64/libflutter.so (offset 0x14e9000)
03-21 00:49:51.165  6455  6455 F DEBUG   :
03-21 00:49:51.165  6455  6455 F DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
```

flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.6.4 20G417 darwin-x64, locale
    en-ID)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
      more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[☠] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (the doctor check crashed)
    ✗ Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message
      below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at
      https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    ✗ FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 5)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```